# Downloaded utf-8 html file cannot be printed to terminal using Python 3

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8

I'm just trying to download a html file with urllib and then printing the html to the terminal.
The html file seems to be properly encoded in utf-8 as the meta tag specifies (saving it to a file and opening it in any other program results in that file being read and shown properly).

The problem is that when I try to print the whole html to the terminal, Python throws an exception related to the encoding, and I'm a bit lost. I though about the encoding of the file and that may be I wasn't properly specifying the encoding. I tried to execute this in cygwin terminal also, and it prints the html although with encoding problems (some characters are wrong).

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gzip
import urllib.request
import sys, codecs

myheaders = dict()
myheaders['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36"
myheaders['Accept'] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
myheaders['Connection'] = "keep-alive"
myheaders['Accept-Encoding'] = "gzip"

request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.seriesyonkis.com", headers=myheaders)
responsehandler = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
rawresponse = responsehandler.read()
rawhtml = gzip.decompress(rawresponse)

rawhtml = str(rawhtml, encoding="utf-8")

print(rawhtml) #Throws encoding related exception
```

And this is the traceback from the windows console:

```
(venv) F:\dev\own\pyscraper>python scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(rawhtml)
  File "F:\dev\own\pyscraper\venv\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position
27973: character maps to <undefined>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The dos console has problems with utf-8. For Python 2.x there is the `winconsole` module. Don't know if that works with Py3..?

Comment: `\u201c` is `“` which is a "smart quote" not a true `"`. You could do a search and replace before parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the page really does have some problematic characters in it. Looking at the html in Safari's "view source" mode, I found the following:

[image]

As you can see, syntax coloring suddenly stopped - a sign that there was some bad character in the source. I don't think you are doing anything "wrong". I do wonder why you would want to dump this text to the console...

Comment: Not really to dump it, but to parse it. I've got some errors while I did that with beautifulsoup. I guess there is a bad character after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to solve this problem. Your terminal doesn't support the characters, that's all.

As an alternative, you can write the data to a file:

```
with open('html.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(rawhtml)
```

Also, if you want to remove a bad character, this could work:

```
html = rawhtml.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
```